# Selenium Python Find Elements by XPath does not return all expected elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, xpath

I am working on a scraping data from a series of tables on an HTML website. The website has varying numbers of tables depending on the input, so I am trying to use: `.find_elements_by_xpath("//table")` to simply get a list with all the table elements on the page.

However, it is only returning the first table on the page in this case. When I use `find_element_by_xpath(//table[2])`, it returns the other table, but using `find_elements` does not.

The website portal is [here](http://imed.med.ucm.es/Tools/rankpep.html), just press send at the bottom. (I am trying to get the data from the results page). I am using Selenium in Python on the Firefox Webbrowser.

Interesting note, the header table has an XPath of `table[1]`, which begs the question of where is `table[0]`.

Comment: how do you know selenium does not return all elements? Please show code, as it should return 2 tables.
About xpath [1] - counter in xpath starts from 1, not 0. So [1] is really first table. and //table[0] does not exist =)

Comment: hey, opened this site again, and there is only 1 table now.

Comment: Hey there, so when I run the following code, it only returns a value of 1, as opposed to the 2 expected. (One table for the header of the page and the other for the data table). `count = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table")        print(len(count))`

Comment: did you try putting explicit wait before taking count?

Comment: @AmrutaPande Hi, Yes I am using an explicit wait before I take count. Again, if I use `EC. presence_of_element_located(By. XPATH, "//table[2]) ` It loads table 2 just fine, but still, the other tables are not found by `EC.presence_of_all_elements_located`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Key here is to wait properly before you navigate to new tab. As after clicking on send a new tab is getting opened. See below code:

```
driver.get('http://imed.med.ucm.es/Tools/rankpep.html')
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@src='/icons/ig_logo.png']")))

send = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Send']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", send)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", send)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2)) #Wait for 2nd tab to open
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
count = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table")
print(len(count))
```

**Out Put:** As on new page there are two tables, it has printed 2
[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for this. Strangely, this code didn't work with a Firefox webdriver, but it inspired me to try Chromedriver. Somewhat inexplicably all the code works now. Thanks for your help!